# Rolling back changes in python if error occurs

Tags: python, bash

I have a script that does many things, including unziping files and creating folders (using os.system and bash if that matters). 
Now, when a error occurs half way through the compilation, folders are left all over the place.
I would like to make a function that says:

if error occurs:
         os.system("rm -rf folder1 folder2)

Is there a if error statement? As far as I know python kills itself if there is a code error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try and except. It will try everything in the try statement and if something fails you can catch it in the exception and say how you want to deal with it.

You can also specify what type of exceptions you want to catch.

```
try:
    # do stuff here
    zipfile.ZipFile(myfile)
except:
    #if something fails catch it here
    os.system("rm -rf folder1 folder2")
```

Heres the link to the docs
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Please suggest that error logs/handling etc... go into the except block and that all program clean-up goes in the finally block. `except` block should be as much error specific as possible. `finally` blocks will happen regardless of whether an exception occurs and regardless whether you catch it or not. This helps with code duplication and DRY principle.